# Php value won't work inside external jquery scipt

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am having a hard time finding a good solution to what I am facing right now. I am currently building an upload function to handle upload files. I used a jquery file upload plugin from [Hayageek](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php). Now the upload works fine but when I moved the script to a separate js file and load it as an external script, the url won't work.

This is the code I used.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#fileuploader").uploadFile({
    url:"<?php echo site_url('document_items/upload') ?>",
    fileName:"myfile"
    });
});
```

Comment: Is this code in .php file?

Comment: @RuchishParikh, no. It's a js file. url only have a php value.

Comment: then you not able to write php code on that file.

Comment: The file needs either .php or .phtml extension to understand the php statements written inside it. External javascript file would not be able to understand it.

Comment: Thanks! now I understand. But is there any way so that I won't use an absolute path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `document.location.origin` or `window.location.protocol`.

```
var baseurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/";
var newurl = baseurl + 'document_items/upload';

    $(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#fileuploader").uploadFile({
    url: newurl,
    fileName:"myfile"
    });
});
```

**For Javascript**

```
window.location.host          #returns host
window.location.hostname      #returns hostname
window.location.path          #return path
window.location.href          #returns full current url
window.location.port          #returns the port
window.location.protocol      #returns the protocol
```

**For Jquery**

```
$(location).attr('host');        #returns host
$(location).attr('hostname');    #returns hostname
$(location).attr('path');        #returns path
$(location).attr('href');        #returns href
$(location).attr('port');        #returns port
$(location).attr('protocol');    #returns protocol
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this one.

Comment: Note that document_items is a file then upload is a method

Comment: yes it will work. We are just giving dynamic base url. Like if your domain is test.com then `window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host` will give you `http://www.test.com/` and then it will append your document_items/upload so your final url become `http://www.test.com/document_items/upload` as your desire url.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112475/discussion-between-claudios-and-ruchish-parikh).

Answer (score 0):

javascript is client side script and php is server side, so you may not use php in javascript file.

I would suggest you to use javascript tag in **php/phtml** as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#fileuploader").uploadFile({
    url:"<?php echo site_url('document_items/upload') ?>",
    fileName:"myfile"
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I am sorry but script tags are not needed inside a .js file.

Comment: I suggested you to use script tag in php/phtml file

Comment: I know this but what I wanted is to use an external js file.